# what to use instead of callback

Tags: ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have such models structure:

```
TestCase has_many :test_case_steps
TestCaseStep  belongs_to :test_case
```

`TestCase` has `status` attribute.

`TestCaseStep` has `status` attribute.

User can change the `TestCaseStep`'s `status`. If all associated `TestCaseStep` objects have status 'passed', I want to change the `TestCase`'s `status`.

User can not manually update the `TestCase`'s `status`.

I think could use some callback, checking all the associated objects' statuses, and once all are `passed`, update the `TestCase`'s one. But using callback where another model is involved is evil.

Please hint me with the direction. May be there exists some *whatcher*/*observer* approach or something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rails-observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) gem is  the Rails 3 observers refactored into a gem.

Also look at [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), to mix in the code you want to do updates.

If you're open to adding a gem, see [wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper), which enables simple publish and subscribe.

Comment: hey, thanks a buucnh for the reply! definitely upvoted, just want to see if anyone else suggests something besides these :)